# Programming an LPC2148 in OSX

Tags: embedded, arm, osx

Right now I'm using HyperLoad to program an LPC2148 through USB. HyperLoad is a windows program and I have a Mac so I have to open up a Windows virtual machine to use it. Is there a way to program it in OSX? I found a program called lps21isp, but I don't know how to use it. Also, don't I need a special driver for OSX so that it can communicate with the ARM7?

Answer (score 2):

If you can some spare money (~$55) to buy a JTAG device (assuming you have JTAG on your board) and a fair amount of time to setup OpenOCD / GNU ARM toolchain / Eclipse IDE. This is definitely not for the faint of heart but it should give you a native OSX environment to work in. This [blog post](http://salvatoremenendez.blogspot.com/2011/08/mac-os-eclipse-openocd-stm32-arm-cortex.html) goes into the exact steps for setting it up. They use an ARM Cortex M3 but this environment is applicable to a majority of ARM families. I have a very similar set up in Windows using an LPC2148. I also found a lot of good info on LPC2148's on [this site](http://jcwren.com/arm/) who developed for the LPC2148 using Linux.

Answer (score 0):

lpc21isp can be used to pogram the chip via a serial interface. I assume your mac does noet have a seruial interface, so you could use an usb-to-serial converter (and a max232 hip to convert back to TTL level/polarity), or buikt one yourself from an FT232 chip. lpc21isp itself is available as C source. I could compile it on windows without any changes, I dunno whether it will compile on your system.